# Property 'direction' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using an Angular 7.x application with a floating action button and when I execute the following command to build in production mode I get some errors in the terminal.

How do I fix this issue as the direction & onToggle already exist?

```
src\app\components\calendar\calendar.component.html(202,9): : Property 'direction' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src\app\components\calendar\calendar.component.html(201,9): : Property 'onToggle' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

// HTML Component

// Typescript Component

```
    // 
    ngcFloatButtonData: Object = {
        direction: 'up',
        open:false,
        onToggle: function(): void {
            this.open = !this.open;
        },
    };
```

// HTML

```
<ngc-float-button
  (click)="ngcFloatButtonData.onToggle()"
  [direction]="ngcFloatButtonData.direction"
```

Comment: You can create a custom class that holds these properties. Also, how are you accessing this object in your template?

Comment: @NicholasK just added the small snippet of the HTML template

Comment: Is your object declared inside a method?

Comment: @NicholasK the ngcFloatButtonData object currently isn't within a method - I tried adding to the constructor now but that gives me an 'Cannot assign to Object because it is a constant' error

Comment: Share the entire .ts file with these new changes.

Comment: OR a stackblitz that replicates the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In typescript one usually defines a class "exampleclass" (exampleclass.ts) like this:

```html
export class exampleclass {
    propertyOne: number;
    propertyTwo: String;
    propertThree: number;
}
```

Also make sure the property you want to access in the template has the right scope -> public

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `ngcFloatButtonData` as `Object`. Declare it as what it is, `NgcFloatButtonComponent`, instead. (Import `NgcFloatButtonComponent` from the library you're using).